# Can import python package in r while the package exists for other python interpreters

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, rstudio, reticulate

With the r package `reticulate`, I attempted to import the python package `scipy` to do my data analysis. However, it says

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'.
```

But when I use jupyter notebook, clearly I can import `scipy` so my computer has the package. Somehow RStudio is not importing it.

This is what I did:

```
library(reticulate) #import reticulate to enable python usage in r
use_python("/usr/local/bin/python3", required = TRUE) #set the path for where my python is.
from scipy.optimize import minimize #try to import the package in a python block
```

Then I get the error package not found. I tried so many things this afternoon but failed

First, I tried to install again using r studio with `py_install("scipy")`. It installs, but when I try to import again, it still reports not module found.

Second, I tried to create virtual environments by `conda_create('r-reticulate', packages = "python=3")` and then `py_install("scipy")`. Doesn't help.

Third, I upgraded the python to python 3.7. Now not only the `scipy` package, but all python packages like `numpy`, `pandas` also could not be imported. Of course they can still be imported in Jupiter notebook so it's not the case that my computer does not have them.

I tried the previous two things again but no help.

```
library(reticulate)
use_python("/usr/local/bin/python3.7", required = TRUE)

from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # for plotting
import numpy as np # for numeric calculations
import pandas as pd # for python data frame
import time
```

I expect to successfully import all the python packages to RStudio. And figure out a way to install new python packages and import them to r.

Comment: Shouldnt you be importing like this ´np <- import("numpy")´ and not ´import numpy´

Comment: It's the same. np <- import("numpy") is for r block, import numpy is for python block